# If animals die why dont plants?

Tags: botany, zoology

I am not a Phd in biology so don't go hard on me.when I was walking to home after swimming class I saw a mouse dead and was intimidated by gods wonder but when I reached home I saw the Devil's ivy and my thoughts flung to the 450 year old tree in my city why didnt it die when the mouse did.

Comment: There are whole large groups of plants that die in a relatively short time.  Annuals, for instance, grow from seed to mature plant, produce seed, and die within the space of a year.  Desert ephemerals are even shorter-lived, compressing the whole sprouting to seed process into the few weeks after a rain.

Comment: rephrase that question to not talk about intimidation by gods, not Phd, walking, swimming, it's a mouse/tree longevity question only.

Comment: plants have a slow metabolic rate. to can go into stasis, they can freeze below -20, they can go without water. complex machinery breaks faster than simple stuff, i.e. a scythe versus a lawnmower.

Comment: Many plants don't have the lifespan of a mouse. Many animals don't have the lifespan of a tortoise. This isn't about Biology. It's about learning. Your question is based on misperceptions.

Comment: PhD in biology?

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by plants don't die? You don't have to have a PhD to comment on this! Haven't you seen dead grass or any dead plant in your life? Some trees have a long lifespan, like the banyan, but they do die. Even turtles have a long life, but that doesn't mean that they don't die.

Answer (score 4):

Plants die of old age too. Trees tend to have a long lifespan but still.... they die of old age.

There are few species that seem to have [negligible sensescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_senescence) such as

- giant tortoise
- greenland shark
- aspen tree root system
- mussel

and some that even seem to never age ([biologically immortalilty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality)) such as

- lobster
- hydra
- some bacteria
- some yeast

but you most definitely cannot make such generality as "animals age, plants don't".